# How do I put a pumpkin on my head in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How does one put a pumpkin on his head in Minecraft? My brother tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you are dragging the pumpkin into your helmet slot.

And note that you can only wear normal pumpkins; Jack'o'lanterns will not work.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work

Comment: I just tried and it does work, so maybe try again and check everything?

Comment: That is the method to wear pumpkins. So I'm not sure what you are doing that it isnt working, can you post a screenshot of the pumpkin you are trying to wear? Also is this Minecraft-PC or a different platform. I am unsure how pumpkins work on pocket edition or 360.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: I agree with this answer, shouldnt be any different then putting on a helm.

Answer (score 1):

You can not be wearing a helmet when you try this. Obvious, but it might be what is wrong

Comment: Won't they switch out or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just place it on the head, but you can also try the command (will only work with commands enabled):

> /replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head minecraft:pumpkin